# New Android Application Project - layout file and activity class are not created by ADT

Tags: android, adt

Environment:  Eclipse ADT Build: v22.3.0-887826, Windows 8.1 Host.

I make the following steps to create new Android project:

File - New Android Application Project. Application Name: Sample, all other fields default: Minimum SDK 8, Target 18, compile with 19. Next.

Create custom launcher - off, Create activity - on. Next.

Blank activity, Next.

SampleActivity, Layout name activity_sample. Finish.

Finally, I open package explorer, Sample - res. Layout directory is empty. src directory is also empty, main activity class is not created.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating ADT to 22.6 using this link 
Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Do you mean Help -Check for Updates function in Eclipse? It gives me the error "Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno". Update dialog is not shown.

Comment: try the link that i wrote above. I had the same issue and experienced the same things

Comment: It looks like my Eclipse doesn't work at all - all Update and Install functions fail. I will try to move to another OS - Windows 7 or Linux, because I also have ADB driver problem here in Windows 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to following: 
*'Help'->'Install New Software'* and type 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it.
It will update the ADT.

Even I had the same problem and my issue got resolved with it!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Mac OsX 10.9.2 and updated to

Android Developer Tools   22.3.0.v201310242005-887826

which is the same version that Alex had the original problem on.  For me, the updating fixed the problem, so I don't think it was the version of ADT that was causing the problem.  Something else in the update process cleared the cause of the problem.  Now, when I create a new Android project, the layout files and activity class is created, as expected.