# Eclipse doesn't create automatically Main Activity and layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I hope every new Android learners are studying hard.

I reinstalled Android, but it doesn`t create MainActivity and layout.xml files automatically.

I followed [Eclipse doesn't create Main Activity and layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219392/eclipse-doesnt-create-main-activity-and-layout) and [New Android Application Project - layout file and activity class are not created by ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421395/new-android-application-project-layout-file-and-activity-class-are-not-created) s but no result.

Any help would be valuable, because I cant solve this. I also reinstalled Java, SDK, JDK and other Android programming tools several times , but no result.

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: Forget to add: there is error message looks like this:[2014-06-29 13:04:16 - appcompat_v7_7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\multiLab\workspace\appcompat_v7_7\bin\jarlist.cache

Comment: What is the API level you creating the project for?

Comment: Have you gone to the android sdk manager and installed and updated everything? As well as going to help<check for updates? Additionally have you made sure you are developing for an api above 11?

Comment: Minimum Required SDK is API 8:Android 2.2(Froyo), Target SDK: API 19: Android 4.4 KitKat and Compile with: API 20: Android 4.4 (KitKat Wear). And also I updated everything as you mentioned above.