# Eclipse is not creating default project and main layout in ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, src

The issue is that upon creating a new project in Eclipse with the ADT plugin it will not display any document in the source folder, also there is a Warning displayed

WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Giovani\Documents\Online Documents\Android App Development\Workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache.

I am using for minimum required sdk API 8: Android 2.2 (Froyo), for the target and compile i have API 21: Android 4.X (L Preview), for the other dialogs i am using the defaults parameters, also i am creating a Blank Activity. When the file is created there is two folders that span, the project folder and a folder called appcompat_v7. I am using Windows 7, 64 bit, i have installed all of the packeges that i could in my SDK manager, and using the lates version of ADT, 23.0.4.1468518. Another problem that i have notice is that the AVD is not allowing me to create a new device when accesed from eclipse. I found post with similar problems but non of the solutions displayed worked for me, some of those are:

[Adt doesn't create default hello world but command line does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203862/adt-doesnt-create-default-hello-world-but-command-line-does/22209435#22209435)

[appcompat_v7: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231174/appcompat-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-t)

[New Android Application Project - layout file and activity class are not created by ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421395/new-android-application-project-layout-file-and-activity-class-are-not-created)

I am a beginner in the field of android development, i will appreciate immensely your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try and resolve the warning.  Make sure the path to

C:\Users\Giovani\Documents\Online Documents\Android App Development\Workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache

exists and you have permission to write to the file and directory.

Comment: It exists, and i have all the permissions to write the file on it. It is possible that i missed something during the installation?